# Why can't we add static methods to enums?

Tags: c#, .net, static, enums

I wonder why we can't add static methods (only methods, not properties) into enums? Is there any explanation for that?

It would be very useful if it was allowed.

And I also want to learn who forbids us to do it? Is it IL or C#?

**Edit:**

I don't want to use extension methods. Because I dont need to pass an instance of that enum. I don't need it's value there...

I want to call something like `FooTypes.GetGoodFoos()` not something `FooTypes.BadFoo.GetSomething()`

**Edit 2:**

Is that only me who thinks this could be more useful rather than writing this method in another class?

```
public enum Colors
{
    Red,
    LightRed,
    Pink,
    /* .
       .
       . */
    Green

    public static Colors[] GetRedLikes()
    {
        return new Colors[]
        {
            Colors.Red,
            Colors.LightRed,
            Colors.Pink
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create extension methods for enums. I think that's cleaner than adding methods - static or not - to an actual enum.

Comment: @bstenzel But to call an extension method we need an instance of that enum. I just want to call `FooTypes.GetValues()` not `FooTypes.FirstValue.SomeMethod()`

Comment: why would you call a method on something that doesn't technically exist yet. Specially Enum the only usefull method i can see is getting the list but that it's simple reflection `Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));`

Comment: @Franck I want to create a method that returns some of the enums' values as an array. Like: `Colors.GetLightColors()`

I don't think this is a bad approach... That could make my codes simpler.

Comment: ya the method i wrote return array of strings. Mentioning that MyEnum IS the enum not value of enum

Comment: @Franck But I'm also asking about IL too in this question. They don't mention it in the other question.

Comment: What benefits of embedding static methods into the Enum you are expecting?

Comment: @Dmitry Added an example under **Edit 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't add methods to `enums` because is how the language is made, and you are free to read the specification of the [**C# Language Specification**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)

> 14.3 Enum members
>
> The body of an enum type declaration defines zero or more enum members, which are the named constants of the enum type. No
> two enum members can have the same name.
>
> > *enum-member-declarations: enum-member-declaration*
> > *enum-member-declarations   ,   enum-member-declaration*
> > *enum-member-declaration: attributesopt   identifier attributesopt*
> > *identifier   =   constant-expression*
>
> Each enum member has an
> associated constant value. The type of this value is the underlying
> type for the containing enum. The constant value for each enum member
> must be in the range of the underlying type for the enum.

Comment: I don't think it is possible(I am waiting to be corrected), but it is surely more simple make a pure reference type which implements your needs

Comment: I know it is not possible but I just wondered why?

Comment: "And I also want to learn who forbids us to do it? Is it IL or C#?" By quoting the C# spec, you're implying that it's C#. Can you write an enum in IL that has a static method?

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: I found out that `enums` are considered as `constant` in **IL**. As we can write a class to contain our static method to make it work, maybe the C# compiler could do it for us too. Right? Something like they are doing with `properties` when it adds `type getFoo()` and `void setFoo(type value)` automatically into the compiled code...

Comment: This does not answer the question.  What was the reasoning behind this decision?

Comment: This is the only answer that addresses the "why" that is the question, but still fundamentally fails to actually answer it. The quote from the spec is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers say, it's not possible.

I know, this does not answer your question, but I want to give an alternative to your example.
Because, basically what you try to archive is already possible with flags. So let me take your "GetRedLikes" example:

```
[Flags]
public enum Colors : byte
{
    Transparent = 0,                                         // = 0 (00000000)
    Red         = 1 << 0,                                    // = 1 (00000001)
    LightRed    = 1 << 1,                                    // = 2 (00000010)
    Pink        = 1 << 2,                                    // = 4 (00000100)
    Green       = 1 << 3,                                    // = 8 (00001000)

    RedLikes    = Colors.Red | Colors.LightRed | Colors.Pink // = 7 (00000111)
}
```

Then `Colors.RedLikes` will contain `Red`, `LightRed` and `Pink`. All the magic is done by bits, as always. Your condition then should look like this:

```cs
Colors c = Colors.LightRed;
if(c & Colors.RedLikes != 0)
{
    // c is red-alike
}
```

Of course, this solution will not allow you to do very complex algorithms, it's no method type replacement. But it allows you to combine more than one enum in a set. If you need further functions, you have to build a method in an extra class.

Comment: In my case what I would like to have is 
"static MyEnum Random { get { return (MyEnum)rand(minEnum, maxEnum) } } // simplified random function to pseudocode".
and then use it like MyEnum x = MyEnum.Random
ofc it's only a syntactic sugar and no question to do the same in other way

Answer (score 6):

I use static class for same cases:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
    Item1,
    Item2,
    Item3
}

public static class SomeEnumHelper
{
    public static SomeEnum[] GetMainItems() 
    {
        return new[] {SomeEnum.Item1, SomeEnum.Item2};
    }
}
```